# Python subprocess.call or Popen limit CPU resources

Tags: windows, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess, google-earth-engine

I would like to set 4 additional properties on 8000 images using the  Google Earth Engine command line tool. Properties are unique per image. I was using Python 2.7 and the subprocess.call(cmd) or subprocess.check_output(cmd) methods.  Both are very slow (takes 9 seconds per image i.e. 20 hours total). Therefore I tried to send the commands without waiting for a response using supprocess.Popen(). It causes my PC to crash due to the amount of tasks (CPU close to 100%)

I was looking for ways to have my PC use say 80% of its CPU or even better, scale down CPU use if I am using other things. I found the os.nice() and nice argument for subprocess.Popen(["nice",20]) but struggle to use them in my code.

this is an example of a command I send using the subprocess method:

earthengine asset set -p parameter=DomWN_month users/rutgerhofste/PCRGlobWB20V04/demand/global_historical_PDomWN_month/global_historical_PDomWN_month_millionm3_5min_1960_2014I000Y1960M01

Comment: Have you thought about using multiprocessing with a limited number of processes? Not sure if that would be a way to go

Comment: I ended up running the script in google's compute engine and cloud shell